# WordPress Polylang plugin - how to properly setup Internal Links

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, permalinks

I am using Polylang plugin for the WordPress Website.

1. Primary language is English.
2. Secondary language is Deutsch.

Home page, other pages and posts contains images and text links - which are internally linked with other articles. All of these anchor texts contains links of primary language. All these links are opening in a new tab.

When someone seeing a page in Secondary lanugage "Deutsch" then she sees images and text links. When she clicks on these links then ideally she should see a page in Deutch language, although, she sees the next page in English language.

What's the solution for this? Is it because the page opens in a new window?

For Polylang -> Settings -> URL Settings
I have selected URL Modification - "The language is set from the directory name in pretty permalinks"

Answer (score 1):

All **internal links** should open **in the same tab**, target="_blank" is an wrong practice!

But this is not the cause of the error. Check the rest of the language plugin settings.

[image: PolyLang plugin settings]

For example, you can visit website, which uses the Polylang plugin and Deutsch as secondary language, like this:

Official website of Nonwovens manufacturer in German https://sinta-d.com/de/hauptseite/

and check how to it code
[image]